# How are Sources mapped to commands in a RPM specfile?

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm, rpm-spec

In an RPM specfile, sometimes I will see:

```
Source0: /some/path/or/url/file.tar.xz
Source1: /another/path/or/url/file2.tar.gz
Source2: /some/path/library.so
Source4: /other/path/icon.ico
...
```

Sometimes there up to 10+ sources, of varying file types. However, many times, I see no reference such as `%{SOURCE1}` later in the file. Are these sources parsed and/or used in cases where there is no reference to them later in the file? I've read [Creating RPM Packages](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-rpm-packages/), but this example is very simple and doesn't include an answer to this specific question. I don't understand the different use-cases for the Source sections.

EXAMPLE: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/libreoffice/blob/master/f/libreoffice.spec Source7, Source9, Source10, and Source11 are not seen referenced anywhere in the specfile.

Comment: Which commands are you talking of, in the title?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a spec file where `Source1:` is used without later referencing it via `%{SOURCE1} `? It would be common for `Source0`, against which `%setup` and `%autosetup` macros are used, but not for the others.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin I gave an example in the question above of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the %build section, there is a line that has:

```
EXTSRCDIR=`dirname %{SOURCE0}`
```

Then later, one of the configure arguments is:

```
--with-external-tar="$EXTSRCDIR" \
```

From there, it uses the tarballs as part of the build. All the Source entries are held in the same directory as part of the package build, so the spec just finds the directory name and refers to that later. (I’m not sure why you put a local path in your example, they’re either a file name or a URL in a normal spec file).

I’m not intimately familiar with the libreoffice build process, but I assume all the Source entries you mentioned get pulled in through the configure argument above.